# Can someone help me with nested-name specifiers in C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates

What's wrong with the following sample code? It doesn't compile in GCC. Why?

```
template <class TA>
struct A
{
    template <class TAB> struct B;
};

template <class TC>
struct C {};


template <class TD>
struct D
{
    template <class TTD> class T {};
};    

template<class TA>
template<class TBA>
struct A<TA>::B : C<typename D<TA>::T<TBA> >
{
    int foo;
};
```

GCC 4.3.4 output:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: expected `{' before ‘>’ token
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
```

Comment: Fix your question title to describe the problem, please.

Comment: I guess a `typename` is missing in some place. Too tired to concentrate, though. I'll leave it to someone else. But I think you should rephrase some parts of your question. Imagine someone finds the question and answers in one year from now. Your frustration will long be gone. The words stay.

Comment: Nice question ... never saw such complex type template!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct A<TA>::B : C<typename D<TA>::template T<TBA> >
```

> For a template-name to be explicitly qualified by the template arguments, the name must be known to refer to a template.
>
> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template

`T` appears after the nested-name-specifier `D<TA>` which depends on the template-parameter `TA`. The construct `D<TA>::T<TBA>` must interpret `T` as the name of a class template and so the `template` keyword is mandated by the Standard at that point.

Answer (score 8):

Clang's error message is a bit more helpful:

```
error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'T' as a dependent template name
struct A<TA>::B : C<typename D<TA>::T<TBA> >
                                    ^
                                    template
```

For more information consider reading the Stack Overflow C++ FAQ ["Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)